# App crashes when Back button is pressed in activity with an updated GridView

Tags: android, gridview, crash

In my app I launch an activity and from there another activity. On the second activity, I show a GridView populated with data. The user can then press a button to delete all the data attached to the GridView. Whenever the user deletes the data and then presses the Back button, the app crashes with a fatal exception. In the code below, logcat indicates that the crash occurred in the ReloadGridView method. There is actually try...catch in this code but that doesn't prevent the fatal error.

I've spent over a day trying to figure out what is causing this but haven't been successful. It will only occur if the underlying data attached to the adapter is deleted AND the Back button is pressed. This code is running on Android 4.1. NOTE: This is a reduced set of code. All the necessary stuff has been stripped out to make it easier to focus on the problem.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  private ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
  private MyAdapter adapterData;
  private GridView gvData;

  // Setup the GridView.
  gvData = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvData);

  adapterData = new MonitorDataAdapter();
  gvData.setAdapter(adapterData);

  new Thread(null, new LoadMyDataRunnable(0, false), "LoadMyDataRunnable").start();
}

private class LoadMyDataRunnable implements Runnable
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    data = GetMyData();

    ReloadGridView reloadGridView = new ReloadGridView();
    runOnUiThread(reloadGridView);
  }
}

private class ReloadGridView implements Runnable
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {

// Tried the following and many other things but a fatal exeption occurs here when the Back button is pressed:
//        adapterData = new MyAdapter();
//        gvData.setAdapter(adapterData);
//        if (data.size() == 0)
//          gvData.setAdapter(null);
  }
}


// Button to delete data.
btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
    // Delete the data.
    SomeMethodToDeleteData();
    new Thread(null, new LoadMyDataRunnable(0, false), "LoadMyDataRunnable").start();
  }
}
```

Log:

```
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415): FATAL EXCEPTION: MonitorDevice.ReloadGridView.run_d99af1dd-b961-4a1f-bea5-4e4bb986e107
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2269)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1030)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15222)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15222)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15222)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15222)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15222)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15222)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2165)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15222)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1870)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1106)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1279)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4238)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4838)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
07-08 11:28:15.421: E/AndroidRuntime(27415):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-08 11:28:15.971: E/WifiHW(427): wifi_send_command : SIGNAL_POLL ; interface index=0;
07-08 11:28:18.981: E/WifiHW(427): wifi_send_command : SIGNAL_POLL ; interface index=0;
07-08 11:28:22.001: E/WifiHW(427): wifi_send_command : SIGNAL_POLL ; interface index=0;
07-08 11:28:25.011: E/WifiHW(427): wifi_send_command : SIGNAL_POLL ; interface index=0;
07-08 11:28:28.031: E/WifiHW(427): wifi_send_command : SIGNAL_POLL ; interface index=0;
```

Comment: Add the logcat output also.

Comment: Setting gvData to null `gvData.setAdapter(null);` is causing `NullPointerException`

Comment: @AndroidDev better post the entire code or locate which line caused NPE. post your adapter code.